# Can a DataBinder.Eval be nested within another DataBinder.Eval?

Tags: asp.net

Can you do something like

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Column1").ToString().Replace("_",<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Column2") %> %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column1")
    .ToString()
    .Replace("_", DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column2").ToString()) 
%>
```

Or even better in your data source add a third column:

```
public string Column3 
{
    get
    {
        return Column1.Replace("_", Column2)
    }
}
```

And then simply:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Column3") %>
```

or even shorter:

```
<%# Eval("Column3") %>
```